# Determine SCCM distribution point server where source file reside

Tags: powershell

I have a script to compare the contents of source and destination folder and just copy the missing ones like below. This is to test on my local machine.

Actually I want to use this code for my application deployment in SCCM. Right now the source path is pointing to my local machine directory. But if I want to deploy this script via SCCM, how do I specify the source path to point to the distribution point server?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$SourcePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\CompareFile1" 
$DestPath = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\CompareFile2" 

$Source = (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse).FullName 
$Dest = (Get-ChildItem $DestPath -Recurse).FullName 


for($i=0;$i -lt $Source.Count;$i++) 
{ 
 $Source[$i] = $Source[$i].Replace($SourcePath, "") 
} 

for($i=0;$i -lt $Dest.Count;$i++) 
{ 
 $Dest[$i] = $Dest[$i].Replace($DestPath, "") 
} 


foreach ($fileS in $Source) 
{ 

$Found = $false 


foreach ($fileD in $Dest) 
{ 

    if($fileD.CompareTo($fileS) -eq 0) 
        {$Found = $true} 

} 

if(-not $Found) {

robocopy /xc /xn /xo $SourcePath C:\Users\admin\Desktop\CompareFile2

  } 

}
```

Comment: From where are you executing this? As the install comand for an SCCM application? If so, you can use `$PSScriptRoot` (PS3.0+) or `$scriptroot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent` (PS2.0). That will point to the local cache for the deployment type or the share if running package from DP

Comment: Thanks. Manage to use $PSScriptRoot. Notice that the path will only be displayed when the script runs.